# Connect Elastic Search using reverse proxied url through Java Code

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, spring-data-elasticsearch

need help on setting up Elastic Search using Reverse proxied URL through Java.

Installed Elastic Search in VM(localhost:9200) which is running on a private corporate network. we enabled reverse proxy for that URL. While pasting the URL in the browser, working fine.

```
https://demo-es.xyz.abc.com

{
  "name" : "13abc1",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "5u9dqlSBRSmpabcdefghij",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.8.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "12341234.......",
    "build_date" : "2020-6-10T03:35:50.234439Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.5.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But I need to connect through Java Code. I'm using the below code to connect but receiving a connection refused.

```
public ElasticSearch(String host, int port, String protocol) throws IOException {
    client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("demo-es.xyz.abc.com", 443)));
}
```

I tried using this as well but not working

```
RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("demo-es.xyz.abc.com", 443, "https")));
```

> Error:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:813)
[]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:248)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1611)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1581)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1551)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:1067)
    at com.presto.banking.util.ElasticSearch.searchRecords(ElasticSearch.java:46)
    at com.presto.banking.util.ElasticSearch.main(ElasticSearch.java:76)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there alternative method to connect Elastic Search through Java Source?

Comment: You might want to check the Elasticsearch server logs to see if there are any clues about why the server closed the connection. If it's a certificate issue, you might need to [tell the client about the CA root certificate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_encrypted_communication.html). If the server requires authentication, you'll need to [pass the credentials](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_basic_authentication.html).

Comment: If it's a certificate issue, the connection might not be making it to the Elasticsearch server... in which case the proxy logs would be the place to look... and the proxy's certificate is the one you'd want to trust.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0, you can configure the RestHighLevelClient like [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest). [This section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration) describes the configuration options in detail.